# Not given a determinant, how can I prove an unknown is invertible?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I recently got stuck in my math homework and I really need help.

Given $(A^2 - A - I  = 0)$, is A invertible? If yes, what is it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Add $I$ to both sides and factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Marcos Escartín Ferrer’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261038/62967) is perfectly fine, but maybe we can try a different path.

*Suppose* $A$ is invertible. I know that you must prove it is, but the temporary assumption might help in finding a contradiction, so $A$ is not invertible, or in finding what the inverse should be.

Since we are assuming $A$ is invertible, we have
$$
A^{-1}(A^2-A-I)=A^{-1}0
$$
and therefore
$$
A-I-A^{-1}=0
$$
so $A^{-1}=A-I$.

OK, we have proved that, if $A$ is invertible, then $A-I$ is the inverse.

Now let's try it! We have
$$
A(A-I)=A^2-A
$$
and we know from the given assumption that $A^2-A=I$. So done! (You probably know that for a square matrix only a one-sided inverse is necessary, but if you don't it's easy to compute also $(A-I)A$.)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $A^2-A=I$ wich can be factorized in two different ways:
$$A(A-I)=I$$
$$(A-I)A=I$$
And that is exactly the definition of inverse matrix. Then $A^{-1}=A-I$.